# How to add a folder to your cmd's path?

Tags: cmd

My current window of the cmd displays this:
C:\Users\Akshat>
I want it to include a folder named 'Python' located in C:\Users\Akshat\Python to the cmd's path environment such that it searches for the entered file name in the mentioned directory as well.

How do I do that?
Thanks, in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the necessary steps here, just BE CAREFUL not to delete any other folders or replace any other characters: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

By using `echo %PATH%` in your cmd you can see if the folder has been appended at the end of the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! Those steps mentioned in the given link worked. Thanks. :)

Comment: Of course. :) Just wait 3 minutes...